# org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver printing value in debug mode

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading jdbc.properties file using properties placeholder as below.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:jdbc.properties" />
```

In the properties file I'm storing jdbc configuration along with password. When I run the springframework in debug mode. It's printing the properties value which is password. Is there any solution to fix this? Here is my log statement.

```
2014-05-20 18:37:32,076 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'database.password' in any property source. Returning [null]
2014-05-20 18:37:32,076 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'database.password' in [localProperties]
2014-05-20 18:37:32,076 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'database.password' in [localProperties] with type [String] and value 'pass'
2014-05-20 18:37:32,076 [main] TRACE o.s.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper - Resolved placeholder 'database.password'
```

Comment: You can add a more specific rule to the logging framework, only for `PropertyPlaceholderHelper` where the level would be INFO or something less

Comment: Since I'm using logback I can add filter, but that is not the solution I'm looking for. As anybody can tamper the log file. Since I'm giving the access to log configuration file

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but I seriously doubt you can disable the logging any other way. Perhaps a custom build of the Spring Framework :)

Comment: So they can access the log but not the property file?

Comment: Yes, log is being sent to another server via syslog.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [this](http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This an old post and I'm not sure if you just want to remove them from the log selectively but for a simple answer I use the following in application.properties.

```
logging.level.root=error
logging.level.com.springcloudexample=trace
```

The second line is the application root namespace.

Comment: No this is not the answer I'm looking for, I'm looking from security perspective, where when I set the logging level to debug, spring framework is printing password parameters as well.